# Flash of content in my jquery accordion

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue on page load with accordion content being shown (jquery)

Here's the current code:

```
if (jQuery('.accordion')[0]) {

    jQuery('.accordion').find('.acc_head').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery(this).next().slideToggle('fast').css('zoom', '1');       
        jQuery(this).parent('li').toggleClass('collapse');

    });

    jQuery('.accordion > li').each(function ($) {

        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('extended')) {

        jQuery(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast').css('zoom', '1');
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('collapse');

        }

    });
}
```

I've got it functioning how I'd like (images that change, based on the expanded/collapsed state, but I'm getting a jump of content when the page loads for the two expanded sections. Here's the html:

```
<ul class="dropdown accordion">
<li class="currentpage">Overview</li>
<li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
<li>
    <a class="acc_head" href="#">Page 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
<li>
    <a class="acc_head" href="#">Page 4</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any thoughts on how I can hide this content from being shown when the page is loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide it with css, either inline or by adding classes to said elements.

```
<li style="display: none;">
```

You can't solve it with javascript because the flash is happening due to the delay between the element existing on the page and the javascript executing.

this is known as a Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

You can make it less obvious and almost unnoticible in some browsers by moving the javascript out of the dom ready handler and immediately after the element being affected, however, in some browsers even that won't be enough.

You may also want to change `jQuery(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast')` to `jQuery(this).find('ul').hide()`